# Creating an activeadmin filter on a scope in ransackable_scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, ransack

I'd like to create an activeadmin filter on a page for a model that has an association with the User model. I'd like to use the custom scope `matches_name`, which combines the `first_name` and `last_name` fields. I've added that scope to the model's `ransackable_scopes` method, and I am able to query it in the rails console.

I've specified the filter like so:

```
filter :user_matches_name, as: :string, label: "User"
```

However, when I load the page, it errors out with this message:

```
undefined method `user_matches_name_contains' for Ransack::Search<class: MyModel, base: Grouping <combinator: and>>:Ransack::Search
```

I've been able to create a filter on the user activeadmin page without a similar error:

```
filter :matches_name, as: :string, label: "User"
```

Is there a way to prevent either ransack or activeadmin from appending the extra `_contains` on the end of the filter?

Comment: The filters argument gives filters to append to the first ransack predicate, so that example attempts to find `:user_matches_name_user_matches_name`

Comment: What happens if you just change it to `filter :user_name_matches, as: :string, label: "User"` and add that as a `ransackable_scope` or better yet maybe create a [custom ransacker](https://activerecord-hackery.github.io/ransack/going-further/ransackers/#concatenated-fields) and utilize that.

Comment: A custom ransacker gets around the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ransacker](https://activerecord-hackery.github.io/ransack/going-further/ransackers/#concatenated-fields) to combine first_name and last_name (full_name for example) for the User class and then from ActiveAdmin resource file that has an association with the User model use this filter:
`filter :user_full_name, as: :string, label: 'User'`

registration of my model resource

```
ActiveAdmin.register MyModel do
  actions :index

  filter :user_full_name, as: :string, label: 'User'
end
```

registration of User resource

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  actions :index
end
```

User and MyModel models

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  def self.ransackable_associations(auth_object = nil)
    %w[user]
  end

  def self.ransackable_attributes(auth_object = nil)
    %w[created_at id id_value updated_at user_id]
  end
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  ransacker :full_name do |parent|
    Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('||', parent.table[:first_name], parent.table[:last_name])
  end

  def self.ransackable_attributes(auth_object = nil)
    %w[created_at first_name full_name id id_value last_name updated_at]
  end
end
```

this code should work properly with both 3.x.x and 2.x.x versions of ActiveAdmin gem